# Trying to find differences of hours between two dates in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff

I've been trying to learn some SQL but I'm rather struggling with the language. I'm trying to find the difference between two dates(departure and arrival) from a table. Other places have stated to use DATEDIFF, though I'm trying to pull the data directly from a table instead of keying in the dates manually. Here's my horrible attempt at trying to use this function

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) as HourDiff;
FROM airlines a
WHERE HourDiff >= 8
```

I'm also trying to find differences of time that exceeds over 8 hours but honestly I really don't know what I'm currently doing... What is the right way I should be writing this?

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: There are some dependecies on the DBMS you're using. So please tag it in your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using this query:

**Syntax for SQL SERVER**

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) as HourDiff
FROM airlines a
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) >= 8
```

**Syntax for MySQL**

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) as HourDiff
FROM airlines a
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour, a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) >= 8
```

Comment: What's the syntax for both TIMESTAMPDIFF and DATEDIFF if I wanted to pull data from a table?

`SELECT DATEDIFF(Difference wanted, tableColumn, tableColumn2) `

What does
`as HourDiff` do

Comment: You tagged the question with MySQL, so you can forget about the syntax for SQL Server. I don't know if I am getting you well, because the syntax for that method is quite well documented in Internet. For example here: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php

Comment: Ah alright then. I got the desired effect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an index on the `departure_time` column, then you might get better results if you use something like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, a.departure_time, a.arrival_time) as HourDiff
FROM airlines a
WHERE a.departure_time >= DATE_ADD(hour, -8, a.arrival_time);
```

---

If you're running **MySQL 5.7** or higher, to get the most out of this query, I'd recommend adding a [**computed column**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to your table:

```
ALTER TABLE airlines 
ADD HourDiff Integer AS DATEDIFF(hour, departure_time, arrival_time);
```

Then I would proceed to create an index on this column:

```
ALTER TABLE airlines 
ADD INDEX HoursDiff_IX (HourDiff);
```

Then you could simplify your query to:

```
SELECT HourDiff
FROM airlines
WHERE HourDiff >= 8;
```

You could even proceed to select more columns in your query and you might possibly get close to similar performance, depending on how many columns you add in your `SELECT` part.